# jquery modal duplication on single ajax page dashboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog, single-page-application

I have an issue where I have 5 jquery dialog in a certain ajax request.  This page doesn't reload, and relies entirely on ajax.  Once this certain ajax request loads with the 5 dialogs, they are initialized, and the plugin adds the necessary markup at the bottom of the page for the dialog .  I leave that page via ajax to go to another ajax request.  That html generated from the modals are still on the page.  If I go back to the page that has these 5 dialogs again, it adds another 5 modals to the html at the bottom, so now that makes 10.  Is there a good way to remove these modals when navigating ajax pages, or do I have to keep track of it?  There are some dialogs that are global, and are used by every ajax request, so a global delete wont work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did somewhat what the lone answer gave, but I already had a common class on these modals so I did this.

```
$(".modal-template").parents('.ui-dialog').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Give each set of dialogs a unique class - perhaps "set" + a unique, incremented variable.  Before incrementing the variable, call, for example `$('.set' + incrementVal).dialog("destroy");` to eliminate the old dialogs, before creating the new ones.  Does that sound like it would work?

For example:

```
globalIncrement = 0;
function createDialogs() {
    globalIncrement += 1;
    $('div#main').append('<div class="set' + globalIncrement + '">test Dialog</div>');
    if(globalIncrement > 1) {
        $('div.set' + (globalIncrement - 1)).dialog("destroy");
        //Also, remove the <div> from the DOM:
        $('div.set' + (globalIncrement - 1)).remove();
    }
}
```